# String Dot String (Mail without Domain) RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, mootools, validation

Really got stuck on this simple regex. Need it to validate a string, that will be a mail without the "@domain.xxx".

It must accomplish the following rules:

- there must be a string (only letters) starting.
- there must be a string (only letters) ending.
- this two strings must be separated by a dot.
- the complete string mustn't contain any numbers or simbols.

I was trying with something like... `/^[a-z]+$/^[.]+$/[a-z]+$/i` ...but no success.

Comment: You have used the beginning/end of line anchors `^$` in places where they can never match, i. e. in the middle of the string. That's probably why your regex fails.

Comment: Oh, and the slash `/` usually denotes the beginning and end of the regex as a JavaScript object, so of course that can't occur within a regex either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/^[A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/
```

will work for ASCII letters.

If you also want to allow international letters (äá etc.) try

```
/^[^\W\d_]+\.[^\W\d_]+$/
```

`[^\W\d_]` means "Any character that not a non-alphanumeric character, not a number and not an underscore".

Comment: `\w` matches *alphanumerics*, so to get alpha only, use `[^\W\d_]` or `[[:alpha:]]`.

Comment: According to the RFC specifications you should probably also consider characters like !, #, and $. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#RFC_specification

Comment: Nice, that's working now. Thanks Tim. :)

I'm hating regexp for a while. :P

Comment: Check http://www.regular-expressions.info for a great tutorial. It's not so bad once you get the hang of it :)

Comment: @Jan: Will consider nothing my boss hasn't asked to do. :)

Answer (score -1):

`/^[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+$/`?

Comment: This would not allow upper case letters.

Comment: You're wrong Jan. It's ok too. I've said nothing about uc or lc. ;)

Comment: @Jan No problem, I can live with it :-) I created that regexp only to show what @Raul missed while creating his version. To add case insensitivity he can add `/i` flag or modify it as shown in another answer.